# Having trouble rendering items in React.js

Tags: html, reactjs

I'm pretty new to React, being very used to OOP this is kind of twisting my brain a bit!

I'm playing around with the PokeAPI, to show different stats of pokemon, I've gotten all my data into the array fine, I've just hit a brick wall when it comes to rendering it, nothing apears.

index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import PokemonRender from './PokemonRender';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <PokemonRender />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

PokemonRender:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

const PokemonRender = () => {
    const pokemonList = [];

    const getPokemonData = async (id) => {
        try{
          const dataArray = [];
          const url = 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/' + id;
          const res = await axios.get(url);
          dataArray.push(res.data);
          pokemonList.push(dataArray[0]);
          dataArray.length = 0;
        } catch(e) {
          console.log(e);
        }
    }
    
    const Pokemon = ({ id, name }) => (
        <div>
          <p>{id}</p>
          <p>{name}</p>
        </div>
    )
    
    useEffect((i) => {
        for(i = 1; i < 152; i++) {
            getPokemonData(i);
    }   }, []);

    return (
        pokemonList.map((pokemon) => (
            <Pokemon id={pokemon.id} name={pokemon.name} />
        ))
    )
}

export default PokemonRender;
```

edit:

I've boiled it down to this, the arrays all contain the right data (which they didn't before) but the return statement isn't returning what it should? Any ideas?

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const Pokemon = ({ id, name }) => (
  <div>
    <p>{id}</p>
    <p>{name}</p>
  </div>
);

const PokemonRender = () => {
  const [pokemonList, setPokemonList] = useState([]);
  const tempPokemonArray = []
  const getPokemonData = async (id) => {
    try {
      fetch("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/" + id).then(res => res.json()).then((pokemon) => tempPokemonArray.push(pokemon))
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  };

  useEffect((i) => {
    for (i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
      getPokemonData(i)
    }
    setPokemonList(tempPokemonArray);
    tempPokemonArray.length = 0;
  }, []);

  return pokemonList.map((pokemon) => <Pokemon id={pokemon.id} name={pokemon.name}/>);
};

export default PokemonRender;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `useState` to make a re-rendering. Without it, React won't understand when to re-render your UI. In your case, you need to update pokemon list with `useState`

Did a small refactoring for your code which are removing `dataArray`, fixing `useEffect`, and moving your `Pokemon` component outside of `PokemonRender` to avoid calling it many times

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const Pokemon = ({ id, name }) => (
  <div>
    <p>{id}</p>
    <p>{name}</p>
  </div>
);

const PokemonRender = () => {
  const [pokemonList, setPokemonList] = useState([]);

  const getPokemonData = async (id) => {
    try {
      const url = "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/" + id;
      const res = await axios.get(url);
      //pokemonList.push(res.data);
      setPokemonList([...pokemonList, res.data]); //add current data to the pokemon list
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const blankArray = new Array(152);
    for (const i = 1; blankArray.length < 152; i++) {
      getPokemonData(i);
    }
  }, []);

  return pokemonList.map((pokemon) => (
    <Pokemon id={pokemon.id} name={pokemon.name} />
  ));
};

export default PokemonRender;
```

`useState` is also asynchronous, so I think you keep updating data and UI at the same time which will make your data unsafe (maybe lost during re-rendering). So you should return data in a new array and then render all of them together. For example

```
const getPokemonData = async (id) => {
        try{
          const url = 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/' + id;
          const res = await axios.get(url);
          dataArray.push(res.data);
          return res.data
        } catch(e) {
          console.log(e);
        }
}
```

Update `useEffect` with a list of pokemon

```
useEffect(() => {
    const blankArray = new Array(152)
    for(const i = 1; blankArray.length < 152; i++) {
       pokemonListData.push(getPokemonData(i));
    }
    setPokemonList(pokemonListData) //only run once   
}, []);
```

Since you're new to these stuff, I'd suggest you follow up [this document](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html)

Comment: where is setState is defined ?

Comment: Thanks, @Iftikhor. I didn't notice it! That's a good catch tho

Comment: Two minor nitpicks: (1) the conventional name for setters is `set……` and not `use……` and (2) instead of using `setX([ ...x ])` you should use `setX(prevX => [ ...prevX ])`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the state to handle data inside the component. You can do it by following [this link](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html).
By the way, you should not `getPokemonData` in the loop like that. It will re-render your component 151 times.

Comment: Thanks! How would you recommend I do that without it being inside the loop?

Comment: You should create a function to query in parallel 5-10 items and set the state when all of them are finished (not each of them is finished). After that, you can call it again (maybe in the scroll event) for the next 5 - 10 items. You should consider the order of items also. The order of the items in your code is unexpected and base on the speed of the request.